# Tomb Raider 2013 Steam Wine - How to compile Wine Patch?

Tags: wine, games, steam

I wanted to install Tomb Raider 2013 over Steam with Wine 1.7.22. The problem is, that the game stops after the profile loader. This problem is well known:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27776&sAllBugs

The solution is to patch the wine source code and compile then. i tried to patch the source code with `patch -p1 < patch.diff`. The output was:

```
patching file dlls/kernel32/sync.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 456.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file dlls/kernel32/sync.c.rej
```

If i go to sync.c and change the code myself, the generated wine executable is extremely unstable, produces windows without text and buttons and more issues...

can anyone hekp me maybe?

thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tomb Raider patch is supposed to work fine with Wine 1.5.

Because I needed more recent unpatched versions of Wine for other applications, and hard drive space is not an issue here, I decided to install and run TR 2013 from a custom Wine installation using a virtual drive from [playonlinux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux) [image: Install playonlinux].

Playonlinux provides a version of Wine (1.5.28-TombRaider) with this patch already included ready for download.

[image]

I found this running TR 2013 (Steam) without issues (except the here still unsolved  360° mouse issue and an incomplete support of an xbox 360 pad) on my 32-bit Wine Nvidia 337 driven system.